# iPhone 7 is not showing notifications for a incoming messages in Messages application

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications

I have iPhone 7 running iOS 11.2.5

iMessages (Messages) application is not displaying any notifications for the messages that is coming from bank.

I checked all the settings for notifications and messages app. All of them are enabled.

Some threads on Apple Community forums says that you need to disable bluetooth.

I don't know. Anyone is facing the same issue?

Comment: Reset & Restore, first fix for multiple 'random issues'.

Comment: Is this a specific iMessage user? (You said “that is coming from bank”).  If that’s the case go to the messages and click the blue circled i in the upper right corner and see if “Hide Alerts” is switched on.

Answer (score 2):

If your iPhone’s date or time is incorrect, that could be the reason why you aren’t getting notifications or alerts promptly.